# ajax returns python array response as string

Tags: javascript, php, python, ajax

I am trying to list, in a select dropdown, some ontology elements using the following ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'get', 
                url:"../py/ConfigOntology.py",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#instance_image_1").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", data).text(data));   

                },});
```

"ConfigOntology.py" is a simple code that extracts and prints two ontology items. However, the ajax takes these two as a single string. Parts of this .py contents that generate the output are:

```
import rdflib, rdfextras, cgitb
from rdflib import Graph

cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print("")

def getImages(results):

    for row in results:
        print (row['storedImage'][50:]) 

sparql = "the query goes here"
results = ConfigOnto.query(sparql)
getImages(results)
```

I tried a php script with a php exec(), which gets the .py output as an array but the ajax also takes that a string. I tried JSON.parse(data) but got error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token K in JSON at position 0" - referring to end of line in in .py output.

So, my "big" question is: **how can I access the ConfigOntology.py output as individual items in the ajax() rather than a string, and what could be a possible fixed code for this problem.**

P.S: this is my first ajax function so please go easy on me.

Comment: How about you actually *output JSON* or another parsable format other than plain text? `json.dump(the_data, sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you should do is to return a JSON Object in the endpoint of your ajax call.

If I understand it correctly right now you try to read the output of a python script in an ajax request which is not the normal workflow for this.

the normal workflow would be **request** (client, your browser) --> **server**(this is in your case the script, but it should really be a server) **--> response** (this can be a json Object or html, in your case it is just the console output.)

so what you need to do is to change your pyhton script that gives a console output into an endpoint of a server, and that endpoint should return a **JSON** response.

here is a simple example of json processing with Flask (a simple python webserver) 
http://code.runnable.com/Up77jfzqtL5FAAAu/json-dumps-and-loads-in-flask-for-python

I hope this can get you started

Comment: Thanks for the tip @matyas

Comment: changing the format of the py script output actually worked.. I have changed the output as print("<option value='"+row['storedImage'][50:]+"'>"+row['storedImage'][50:]+"</option>")

Comment: also received it in the ajax as html, which worked...thanks a lot for the tip